# hover on one div lights up another corresponding

Tags: css

I have svg paths showing statistics about letters a-z.
I have corresponding divs with the letter itself.
Each div should colorize corresponding svg path when hovered.
Is it possible to use CSS only to define the relation ships?
I mean, not a way where I have 26 definitions in the css, describing relation of every div

logic like

```
div.a has been hovered, colorize path.a
div.b has been hovered, colorize path.b
...
```

what I have for now is this.

```
<body>
  <svg height="210" width="400">
    <path class="U" d="M 0 300 L 200 0 L 400 400" />
    <path class="T" d="M 0 400 L 200 0 L 400 150" />
    <!-- ... -->
  </svg>
</body>
```

I am trying to find solution for the divs, hoping it wouldn't need JS

Comment: Can you show the HTML? If I knew the structure, maybe I could help with a css selector.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Comment: It depends on your HTML structure...

Comment: @JSScratchDouble thanks! well, that pretty much open and not given for now. It can easily adjust I believe.

Comment: You'll probably need to provide the `div` with an `id` instead of a classname. Your question is also incomplete.

Comment: For the logic you require it will definitely require JS if you want to avoid the 26 rules you don't want.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer to this is that is is only possible if the `div` contains the `path`. Something like this for instance:

```
/* HTML */
<div class="example-div">
    <svg class="example-svg" height="210" width="400">
        <path class="U" d="M 0 300 L 200 0 L 400 400" />
        <path class="T" d="M 0 400 L 200 0 L 400 150" />
    </svg>
</div>

/* CSS */
.example-div {
    fill: white;
}

.example-div:hover {
    fill: black;
}

.example-svg path {
    fill: inherit;
}
```

If the `div` does not contain the `path` then as far as CSS is concerned it has no knowledge of it.